# Database structure linking users and media

Tags: database, django, django-models

Supposing a large number of users and a large number of videos, what would be a better way to structure the database of the following two options:

Option one --

```
class UserProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video, blank=True)

class Video(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    file = models.FileField(...)
```

Option two --

```
class UserProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

class Video(models.Model)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    file = models.FileField(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Videos have nothing to do with user profiles, so the first relation is fallacious. It will also require spanning another table in order to find a user's videos. Use the second.

Comment: +1 but ditch the UserProfile if there are going to be no fields except for user. It becomes useless.